# Cordova error when creating new project

Tags: cordova

When i try create a new android application using cordova/phongap I get the below error:

```
Dean-MacBook-Pro:proj dean$ sudo cordova create HelloWorld4 
com.example.hello3 "Hello world3"
[Error: downloaded www assets in /Users/dean/.cordova/lib/www/cordova/2.9.0/www does not contain index.html, or www subdir with index.html]
```

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was an issue with the version of Cordova. Fixed it by uninstalling the current version and then proceeded to installing a specific version as follows:

Dean-MacBook-Pro:proj dean$ sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
unbuild cordova@2.9.2
Dean-MacBook-Pro:proj dean$ sudo npm install -g cordova@2.8.0

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it moving ~/.cordova/lib/www/cordova/2.9.0/cordova-app-hello-world-2.9.0-64da512 to ~/.cordova/lib/www/cordova/2.9.0/www

Comment: remove your folder app before run `cordova create´

Answer (score 2):

Just remove your  ~/.cordova folder and run again

```
#phonegap create YourApp
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

Look into 
.cordova/lib/www/cordova/2.9.0/cordova-app-hello-world-2.9.0-64da512/

copy the www directory into 
 .cordova/lib/www/cordova/2.9.0/